# I can't get data from Cursor Object

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I've following table structure in my SQLite Database.
[image]

In my SqliteOpenHelper class, I wrote following method.

```
public Form getAllForms(){
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+FORM_TABLE, null);
   int count = cursor.getCount();
   String formID = cursor.getString(0);
   Form form = new Form();
   form.setId(formID);
   cursor.close();
   db.close();
   return form;
}
```

I'm sure there's some data in it because I already watched `count` in debugging mode and I saw the quantity of row that actually existing in database. But CursorIndexOutOfBoundException shows up at cursor.getString(0). plus cursor.getInt(0) and cursor.getString(1) didn't work also. What's the problem might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the cursor to a valid row.

Valid rows are indexed from 0 to count-1. At first the cursor will point to row index -1 i.e. the one just before the first row.

The canonical way of looping through all rows is

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
         // now access cursor columns
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: `while (cursor.moveToNext()) { ... }` would be even simpler.

Comment: @CL. It assumes the cursor is at -1, which is a valid assumption here but not everywhere.

Comment: Yap.., I just forget to moveToFirst. Thank you so much laalto.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `moveToFirst()` to get to the first row before asking for values:

```
  if ((cursor!= null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0)) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
}
```

So Simply use your code as

```
public Form getAllForms(){
   Form form = new Form();
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+FORM_TABLE, null);
    if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0)) {
              cursor.moveToFirst();
          while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
              String formID = cursor.getString(0);
              form.setId(formID);
         cursor.moveToNext();
        } 
     cursor.close();
    }
   db.close();
   return form;
}
```

Comment: The `null` check is not needed. The `while` loop will never end.

Comment: @CL. it checks whether the cursor is after the last result and if false it will exists from loop

Comment: But the cursor is never moved after the last row.

Comment: @CL yes then it will return false and exists from loop.

Comment: Yap.. I need to put moveToFirst(). Thank you so much all...!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
       try {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {

            Form form = new Form();
                              form.setId(formID);

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
                   } finally {
        // database.close();
        cursor.close();
        dbHelper.close();
    }
```